# Entity framework data context does not contain a collection of my entity that uses inheritance. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-4, model

I am using a model with Entity Framework that takes advantage of inheritance. I have one entity for the base type called "User" and two entities that inherit from it ("Admin", and "Worker"). Here is the model:

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

The problem is that when I create my Entity Framework container it does not have a collection of workers or admins on it, only users.

```
EntityContainer context = new EntityContainer();
context.Users; // Exists.
context.Workers; // does not exist.
```

How can I get a collection of workers/admins and not just generic users? Likewise, how can I give my `FamilyAccount` entity a navigation property for Admins and Workers, not generic users?

PS - I am using the [table-per-type](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bags/2009/03/06/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance/) model for my inheritance, if that matters.

`.OfType` seems to work well. Is there another way to actually add a navigation property for just workers or admins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-3.aspx

This article describes how to extend an entity and add a navigation property yourself. Scroll to the "Build Specific Department Query" header. This is what I was after, eliminating the requirement of using `.OfType<Worker>()`.

Now I can do `familyAccount.Admins` and all is good in the neighborhood.

Comment: I'm not criticizing, but what happens when you click UPDATE on your model?  Does your manual association disappear or is it preserved?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's the behaviour of EF.
If you want to navigate to Admin and Worker, you can do the following :

```
var admins = context.Users.OfType<Admin>();
var workers = context.Users.OfType<Worker>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Table-per-Type (TPT) Inheritance involves storing all properties from the base type in a single table. Table-per-Concrete Type (TPC) Inheritance involves storing the data for each type in a completely separate table with no foreign key constraints between them.

If you would like separate tables for Admins and Workers then you should probably be using TPC.

Comment: No, [TPT](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-2.aspx) involves storing all types in separate tables. Storing all in one table is called [Table-Per-Heirarchy](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-1.aspx). I am using TPT and they are already separate tables. Users, Admins, and Workers have their own tables. [TPC](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx) is an edge-case and is entirely different from my needs.

Comment: No, TPT stores all the common data members in a single table. All unique data members then go in their appropriate class tables. TPH puts ALL of the data members in one table and uses discriminators to see which subclass it is.

Comment: Right, which is what I just said. TPC is not what I need here as it's used when there are overlapping fields, of which I have none. I've provided you links to articles describing each, if you have some information that negates the information I provided, please link me to it.

Comment: So you want your table structure to stay the same, but you want to be able to access a list of the subclasses directly from the context?

Comment: The table structure is fine. The base class has a table and the inheriting classes have their own tables. I just want a way to tack on a navigation property to all users of a specific type. Which, I found one in one of the articles I linked to you and am about to post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes. It extends the entity. I should have thought of that myself but oh well.